# Retrieve file permissions from SharePoint via Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

Lets say I have a file on SharePoint. I would like to see which permissions this file has using Power Automate. Is there a way to retrieve such information?

[image]

I don't seem to be able to find the correct option in Power Automate.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into supporting REST API's for this?  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/33b9faa3-067e-42c8-8190-4f80d640cde4/rest-api-get-permissions-for-a-given-document-library-folder-returns-large-amounts-of-data?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no direct action for this, but you can get it by making use of the rest services.

_api/web/lists/getByTitle('LISTNAME')/items(ITEMID)/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings

[image: Example]

This will return all the permissions.

[image: Results]